# Sum of formulas (not numbers)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want a kind of formula that applies any kind of formula to numbers before summing them.
e.g: 
I have values of an angle at column A and I want the sum of the cosine of those angles.

Alternatives like adding another column to calculate the cos then finding its sum will not help since I particularly want to sum the difference between all of values of a column and each single value as a part with other multiplications
e.g

```
    A   B
1   7  
2   11
3   9
4   8
5   6
```

I want for cell B1 to have the sum of all numbers after subtracting A1 from each one
same       cell B2 to have the sum of all numbers after subtracting A2 from each one.

Comment: `=SUM($A$1:$A$5-A1)` This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: nah, not as bad question as it looks... actually, you can't do this with an array formula, nor with a normal one... interesting. I mean, your 2nd question,.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have just tested that, and A1 doesn't change, so it won't work

Comment: @vicap You have to put the formula in B1, Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy down and it will change.  If you try to put the whole column in at once you are correct it will not change.  But do it in the first cell, then copy down. I get, starting in B1 6,-14,-4,1,11

Comment: @ScottCraner OOOOO, I haven't thought of that! Nice! :)

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner , but can u explain to me what the Ctrl-Shift-Enter do?

Comment: It is how you tell Excel that the formula you typed is an Array formula.  So when you are done typing the formula in the formula bar, instead of hitting enter or tab to close the edit, you would hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  An array formula cycles through the ranges and preforms what is asked.  So in this case it is taking each number in the range and subtracting the  number in A1 and then it sums the results.

Comment: thanks again :)  @ScottCraner

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without resorting to an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$5)*1-A1)
```

[image]